# Scheduled Job -- Mail report - cannot find InstanceID

Tags: civireport, reports, scheduled-job

Set up schedule job for mail reports.   the following error is in the log:

---

Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: Report Mail Triggered... Required parameter missing: instanceId

Details

Parameters raw (from db settings):
instanceID=1
format=csv

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceID";s:1:"1";s:6:"format";s:3:"csv";}

Full message:
Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: Report Mail Triggered...
Required parameter missing: instanceId

---

Have tried multiple options for parameters and spelling - i.e. lower case and different report IDs that are known to exist.  All give the same error.

Comment: How are you running the job? This works for me: `cv api --user=cmsadmin job.mail_report instanceId=1 format=csv`

Answer (score 3):

You have instanceID with a capital D. It wants instanceId.

Comment: Yup!    what's the embarrassed emoji?   Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after upgrading (was very many versions behind).

I had trouble finding where to enter the parameter in the dashboard, but it's in "Settings - Scheduled Jobs", Mail reports. Then I edited and added "instanceId=1
format=csv" to the Command Parameters and saved. Went to more > Execute now and it worked.

Comment: THANKYOU! For others - make sure you put each parameter on a new line i.e. `instanceId=1` on the first line and `format=csv` on a new line.